# Soul evolution in Hinduism

Tags: atma, maya, samsara

I'm curious about cultures and religion. As I have been browsing through Wikipedia I have found this:

> Māyā is also a spiritual concept connoting "that which exists, but is constantly changing and thus is spiritually unreal", and the "power or the principle that conceals the true character of spiritual reality".

These are quotes from western studies, but taken from the page of [*Maya (illusion)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_(illusion)). I want to know if one can found proof in the sacred texts that support this vision i.e. *that the soul is immutable*.
I am familiar with the concept of *samsara*, but as I view it, a man tries to reconnect with his soul throughout all the reincarnations.
Otherwise, what is the view in hinduism on the evolution of the *atma* of a man?

Comment: The term "*Atma*" is termed differently by different people. The real term is "आत्म" and not "आत्मा". It means "self". According to Bhagavad Gita, the *Atma* is in **oneness** (not one or two or many). A man, a leopard, an insect, you & me would be sharing the same *Atma*. Though not describable, this "self" is perceived as distortion-less, hence there is **no evolution** for *Atma*. It remains as it is just a witness of everything.

Comment: So a man's soul belongs to Atma just as much as an animal's?

Comment: But what gives man his uniqueness is it's not _his share_ of Atma?

Comment: Think *Atma*'s virtual form as an "ocean" and various species as various forms of "water bodies", such as drops, waves, splash, bubbles... Though all of them appear different, they all are in oneness. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19985/1049). Suppose you are Brahman then the various bacteria or blood cells or body parts will be separate entities, though they appear different, they are in oneness (your body).